# How is the "__block" keyword in Objective-c used?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Just noticed the `__block` keyword in some Objective-c code like the following:

```
// myString passed into the method
__block NSString *_myString = myString;
```

How does the `__block` keyword change the behavior of the above code?

Comment: Matt Gallagher has a [great writeup about blocks](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/10/how-blocks-are-implemented-and.html), including a section on `__block` qualified values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This variable modifier gives the ability for the variable to be modified in block's scope.

Answer (score 0):

With only the statement above the __block modifier won't do anything.  In the context of a block however, the __block allows blocks defined in this method to mutate the variable.

```
__block NSString *myString = @"My string";
NSLog(@"myString: %@", myString);


dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    myString = @"My string changed.";
});

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSLog(@"myString: %@", myString);
});
```

In this example, the blocks can change myString to point to a new variable.  It's analagous to passing the variable by reference.  If I remove the __block modifier from the declaration of myString I would get a compilation stating, "Variable is not assignable (missing __block type specifier).

Answer (score 0):

It allows several things:

1. It allows the variable to be assigned to inside a block that captures it.
2. It allows the block to see changes to the value of the variable after the block was created.
3. Under MRC, a `__block` variable of object pointer type is not retained by the block when the block is copied.